# Make JQuery 1.6 and 1.8 co-exist

Tags: jquery, virtuemart, template-framework

I'm having a lot of troubles with JQuery libraries...

I'm fixing a client's website...

He has VM2 and Joomla 2.5. VirtueMart 2 uses JQuery 1.6; but the template of the website, which uses Helix framework, uses JQuery 1.8, even 1.7...

Is there anyway to make JQuery 1.6 and 1.8 co-exist?

If I enable JQuery 1.6 with JQuery Easy:

- Coments tabs, Fancybox, Slider and Login pop-up won't work...

If I enable JQuery 1.7 / 1.8:

- Products variants and 'add to cart' from Product details won't work...

So... what should I do?

**You can check the website in the next link: http://www.benaventegrow.com/**
**I have enabled JQuery 1.6.4 with JQuery Easy**

**UPDATED**

I have managed to make all the page works but product variants. I need to implement JQuery 1.6.4 for making it work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It occurs to me that running two different versions of jQuery on the same site will give you a lot of headaches, and a lot of coding challenges unless you're a very experienced coder.

A quick Google search [revealed that it might be possible](https://forum.virtuemart.net/index.php?topic=119638.0) to use jQuery 1.7 with VM:

> If your template uses bootstrap.js then to solve a script error with
>   VirtueMart's jQuery (version 1.6.4) you can replace that VM version
>   with jQuery 1.7.1 - in com_virtuemart/assets/js/ the script is named
>   jquery.min.js   VirtueMart 2.0.x and fancybox will still work with
>   that version.

You should try that solution first.

If it fails, there is a way to run multiple versions of jQuery:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='path/to/jquery_1.8.js'></script>  
<script type='text/javascript'>  
 var $jq = jQuery.noConflict();  
</script>  
<script type='text/javascript' src='path/to/jquery_1.6.js'></script>
```

Now `$jq` belongs to jQuery 1.8, and `$` to jQuery 1.6. Finally you have to go through your template code and change the jQuery code accordingly.